# Display no results message for input filtering a list of cards

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input field which is filtering a list of cards.

I can't seem to figure out how to display a message when all the div's are assigned the class display-none. Is their a way to check if any of the div's inside a parent div contain a class? Maybe I am approaching this incorrectly. Thanks for your help!

```js
function mySearch() {
  const input = document.getElementById("cardSearch").value.toUpperCase();
  const cardContainer = document.getElementById("cards");
  let cards = cardContainer.getElementsByClassName("card");

  for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    let noResults = document.getElementById("no-results");
    let title = cards[i].querySelector(".card-content div.card-title");
    if (title.innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(input) > -1) {
      cards[i].classList.remove("display-none");
      cards[i].classList.add("displaying");
    } else {
      cards[i].classList.add("display-none");
      cards[i].classList.remove("displaying");
      checkDisplay();
    }
  }

  function checkDisplay() {
    let noResults = document.getElementById("no-results-message");
    for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
      if (cards[i].classList.contains("displaying")) {
        console.log("something");
      } else {
        console.log("no cards are displaying");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.display-none {
  display: none;
}

.displaying {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-form" style="margin: 1.2em 0 1.2em 0">

  <input onsearch="mySearch()" type="search" id="cardSearch" class="card-search" placeholder="Search for a service..." onkeyup="mySearch()">

</div>

<div class="card-container" id="cards">
  <div class="no-results-message display-none" id="no-results">There are no results.</div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-image" style="background-image: url('/ImageRepository/Document?documentId=113953');">
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="card-title">Abandoned Vehicle Complaint</div>
      <div class="card-body">Report abandoned vehicles in unincorporated Pierce County.</div>
      <div class="link-list row">
        <!-- -- begin accordian ---->
        <div class="accordion-content">
          <div class="accordion-item">
            <header class="item-header">

              <h4 class="item-question">Select an Option</h4>
              <div class="item-icon"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" style="font-size: 12px;" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            </header>
            <div class="item-content">

              <p class="item-answer">
                <br>
              </p>

              <ul>
                <li><a href="https://pals.piercecountywa.gov/palsonline/#/app/srs/issue" target="_blank">Vehicle on Private Property</a></li>
                <li><a href="/1942/">Vehicle on Public Property with a license plate</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://seeclickfix.com/web_portal/TKWgpFXYKgCQQaGg9fixGNSh/report/category/34998" target="_blnk">Vehicle on County roadway</a></li>
              </ul>

              <p>
                <br>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- -- End accordian ---->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- -- end of container ---->
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-image" style="background-image: url('/ImageRepository/Document?documentId=113954');">
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="card-title">Adopt-a-road Pick Up Request</div>
      <div class="card-body">Request bag pick up or sign up for the adopt a road program.</div>
      <div class="link-list row">
        <!-- -- begin accordian ---->
        <div class="accordion-content">
          <div class="accordion-item">
            <header class="item-header">

              <h4 class="item-question">Select an Option</h4>
              <div class="item-icon"><i style="font-size: 12px;" class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            </header>
            <div class="item-content">

              <p class="item-answer">
                <br>
              </p>

              <ul>
                <li><a href="https://seeclickfix.com/web_portal/TKWgpFXYKgCQQaGg9fixGNSh/report/category/35008" target="_blank">Existing approved participant pick up</a></li>
                <li><a href="/2822/">Apply for the adopt-a-road program</a></li>
              </ul>

              <p>
                <br>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- -- End accordian ---->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please put your markup and script in the same snippet so we can see the problem.

Comment: Sorry about that, I am new. I just updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing display only with `.display-none` in css works more clearly

```js
function mySearch() {
  const input = document.getElementById("cardSearch").value.toUpperCase();
  const cardContainer = document.getElementById("cards");
  const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

  [...cards].map((card) => {
    const noResults = document.getElementById("no-results");
    const title = card
      .querySelector(".card-content div.card-title")
      .innerText.toUpperCase();

    title.includes(input)
      ? card.classList.remove("display-none")
      : card.classList.add("display-none");
    checkDisplay();
  });

  function checkDisplay() {
    const noResults = document.getElementById("no-results");
    const result = [...cards].filter((card) =>
      card.classList.contains("display-none")
    );

    cards.length === result.length
      ? noResults.classList.remove("display-none")
      : noResults.classList.add("display-none");

    for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
      if (cards[i].classList.contains("display-none")) {
        console.log("no cards are displaying");
      } else {
        console.log("something");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.display-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-form" style="margin: 1.2em 0 1.2em 0">

  <input onsearch="mySearch()" type="search" id="cardSearch" class="card-search" placeholder="Search for a service..." onkeyup="mySearch()">

</div>

<div class="card-container" id="cards">
  <div class="no-results-message display-none" id="no-results">There are no results.</div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-image" style="background-image: url('/ImageRepository/Document?documentId=113953');">
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="card-title">Abandoned Vehicle Complaint</div>
      <div class="card-body">Report abandoned vehicles in unincorporated Pierce County.</div>
      <div class="link-list row">
        <!-- -- begin accordian ---->
        <div class="accordion-content">
          <div class="accordion-item">
            <header class="item-header">

              <h4 class="item-question">Select an Option</h4>
              <div class="item-icon"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" style="font-size: 12px;" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            </header>
            <div class="item-content">

              <p class="item-answer">
                <br>
              </p>

              <ul>
                <li><a href="https://pals.piercecountywa.gov/palsonline/#/app/srs/issue" target="_blank">Vehicle on Private Property</a></li>
                <li><a href="/1942/">Vehicle on Public Property with a license plate</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://seeclickfix.com/web_portal/TKWgpFXYKgCQQaGg9fixGNSh/report/category/34998" target="_blnk">Vehicle on County roadway</a></li>
              </ul>

              <p>
                <br>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- -- End accordian ---->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- -- end of container ---->
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-image" style="background-image: url('/ImageRepository/Document?documentId=113954');">
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="card-title">Adopt-a-road Pick Up Request</div>
      <div class="card-body">Request bag pick up or sign up for the adopt a road program.</div>
      <div class="link-list row">
        <!-- -- begin accordian ---->
        <div class="accordion-content">
          <div class="accordion-item">
            <header class="item-header">

              <h4 class="item-question">Select an Option</h4>
              <div class="item-icon"><i style="font-size: 12px;" class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            </header>
            <div class="item-content">

              <p class="item-answer">
                <br>
              </p>

              <ul>
                <li><a href="https://seeclickfix.com/web_portal/TKWgpFXYKgCQQaGg9fixGNSh/report/category/35008" target="_blank">Existing approved participant pick up</a></li>
                <li><a href="/2822/">Apply for the adopt-a-road program</a></li>
              </ul>

              <p>
                <br>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- -- End accordian ---->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```